# React binding events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind

Why do I have to bind onClick method?
In this case "this" refers to App class, render method or DOM element?

[image]

Comment: Binding the context may be confusing, especially for newcommers. I would suggest you to use *arrow function* instead, which holds the proper context.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function without bind way will set its context (this) to a global variable of an environment on which your JavaScript operates. In browsers, it is a window global variable.

`bind` is just core javascript. It's how binding events works. It's not a React concept.

Instead of binding a function inside the event handler, you can bind it in constructor itself.

```
constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind onClick because if you do not then this will refer to the global Object.

On the other hand if your onClick is defined inside any html tag like

Select is also considered as an element in reactjs and it provides its own **this** with which onClick event is binded.

So if you do not bind your event to local this of **Select** then it will throw an error

> typeError:function not defined

So binding is mendatory.

Same applies if you are returning anything from with in a map like

```
this.state.something.map(function(holidays,i) {

return  
  <div>
    <Select onClick="this.function"/>
  </div>
}, this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Up **ES6** you can change function "handleChange"  like this :

```
handleChange = () => {
  this.setState ({checked: !this.state.checked});
}
```

Now you can call this function: `onChange = {this.handleChange}` . Hope will help you :)

Comment: Thank Alireza for update my answer ^^. i ' m newbie on stack overflow :D

Answer (score -1):

`this` is the `App` instance in this case.

As for what [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) does, the documentation describes it pretty well:

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, [...]

If we didn't bind `this` (the `App` instance) to our handler function, then when `handleChange` is fired, the `this` inside of that function would be the `<input>` element that contains the `onChange` event handler.

By using `bind`, we force `this` to be the `App` instance inside of the `handleChange` event handler.